# Flutter QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission keeps getting re added

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

I've been trying to upload my app to the google play store but keep getting rejected due to QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission Policy: Less broad app-visibility method should be used, I've gone to the AndroidManifest.xml several times and removed it, but whenever I build the app bundle it gets re-added an I have no idea why.

These are the dependencies I'm using

```
cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
cloud_firestore: ^4.5.0
firebase_auth: ^4.4.0
flutterfire_ui: ^0.4.3+20
fluttertoast: ^8.1.1
image_picker: ^0.8.7+5
firebase_storage: ^11.2.0
firebase_core: ^2.3.0-beta
url_launcher: ^6.1.11
```